# Show that if $AX=BX$ not necessarily $A=B$ without using an inverse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

I'm trying to solve this problem:

If $A, B$ and $X$ are squared matrices with $X\neq 0$ and $AX=BX$, not 
necessarily $A=B$. What is the condition for A = B?

I know that X must be non-singular because

$$ AXX^{-1}=BXX^{-1} $$ 
$$ \Rightarrow AI=BI \Rightarrow A=B.$$

My question is: Is there another way to show this?

Comment: Let $A$ be any non-zero matrix such that $AX = 0$. Then for any matrix $C$ such that $CA \neq A$, we still have $(CA)X = C(AX) = C0 = 0 = AX$.

Comment: Note that the question isn't asking you to find conditions for it to work, it's asking you to show that it isn't necessarily true - i.e. find a counter-example.

Comment: If $\mathbf{x}$ is a column vector such that $A \mathbf{x} = 0$, then by replicating the column $n$ times, $A [ \mathbf{x} \mathbf{x} \cdots \mathbf{x} ] = 0 = 0 \cdot [ \mathbf{x} \mathbf{x} \cdots \mathbf{x} ]$ also.

Comment: Have you looked at diagonal matrices?

Answer (score 5):

You have successfully argued that if $X$ is non-singular, then $A=B.$  However, you have not yet ruled out the possibility that there exists a singular $X$ and yet it is still the case that $A$ must equal $B$

$AX = BX\\
(A-B)X = 0$

If $X$ is singular it has a non-trivial left null space. There exist matrices $A,B$ with $A\ne B$ such that $(A-B)X = \mathbf 0$

If X is non-singular the left null-space is trivial and it must be the case that $A=B$

Comment: I tried to do this:

$$AX=BX \Rightarrow AX-BX=0\Rightarrow (A-B)X=0$$.

Doing $C=A-B$ we have $CX=0$. So

$$det(CX)=det(C)det(X)=0$$

Thinking $det(X)\neq0$ we have $det(C)=0$

$$det(C)=det(A-B)=det(A)-det(B)\Rightarrow det(A)=det(B) $$

but here is the problem, I can't affirm that $A=B$ using the result of the determinant. 

And I need a solution that does not involve any results of inverse matrix

Comment: Why are you calculating determinants?  It is entirely uncessary.  You shouldn't be assuming that $det X \ne 0$  I have already given you your entire proof in two lines.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something along these lines:

matrix multiplication is basically a set of inner products for each element, which in your case results in $\bf a_i \dot x_j = b_i \dot x_j$  While the equivalence of the dot product itself does not imply that $\bf a_i = b_i$ For a single $\bf x_j$, see if you can make an argument that if it must hold for arbitrary $j$, then $\bf a_i = b_i$ if $X$ is not the null matrix.